# Visual Studio Code: Intellisense / 'Go to Definition' possible when using .pyd file without corresponding .py file? (pywin32)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pywin32

I'm currently thrashing around in the bushes, searching for a way to get Intellisense / go to definition to work with this marvelous pywin32 module, so as to glean some sort of insight into its many intriguing methods (win32crypt.CryptUnprotectedData for example).

'Go to Definition' yields the error, 'The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.'

One explanation I tripped over gave some explanation about how a .pyd file without a corresponding .py file is unusual, or potentially done purposefully to obfuscate the source, whereas another suggested the possibility of a caching issue.

I've installed the package using pip, then by using **pywin32-226.win-amd64-py3.7.exe** for good measure; most likely a foolish move.

Is there any solution to be found, or did I just ask another question to set off my ignorance to further advantage?

Comment: So at the end, what is the question?

Comment: Basically the title - if you could imagine how it might be phrased by a moderately capable writer. Is it possible to have those features available when using a .pyd file without a corresponding .py file (within a given package / module). pywin32 -> win32crypt.CryptUnprotectedData just happens to be the example I've been working with.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, didn't work with *VSCode*. *PyCharm* does smth like: `def CryptUnprotectData(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown`,
`pass`, but I think that's far away from your goal.

Comment: That's still more information than I'm getting from VSCode. Interesting.